# Error ' 'numeric' is not a recognized built-in function name. '

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to convert data type from `nvarchar` to `numeric`, but receive an  error:

> `numeric` is not a recognized built-in function name.

Which the other device can be used normally:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(numeric(38,2),Usage_Amount) as Result
    FROM [MMS].[dbo].[Tooling_DieCut]
    WHERE Tooling_Type = 'Solid Tool'
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2):

Use Decimal instead of Numeric...

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(38,2),Usage_Amount) as Result
    FROM [MMS].[dbo].[Tooling_DieCut]
    WHERE Tooling_Type = 'Solid Tool'
```